# SpatiaLite / SQLite -- error: tracks.geom violates geometry constraint [geom-type or srid not allowed]

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I am working with an Elixir struct that looks like

```
%Geo.MultiLineStringZ{
  coordinates: [
    [
      {18.68056, 54.695338, 15.6},
      {18.68061, 54.695331, 15.6},
      {18.68069, 54.695339, 15.6}
    ]
  ],
  srid: 3857,
  properties: %{}
}
```

And I am trying to WKB or WKT encode it and store it in a SpatiaLite DB created like so

```
 SELECT AddGeometryColumn('tracks', 'geom', 3857, 'GEOMETRYZ', 'XYZ');
```

I have also tried using MULTILINESTRINGZ, LINESTRING, and other combinations (e.g., SRID 4326). At this point, I am just throwing darts obviously

Trying to insert directly in `spatialite>` I get the error

```
spatialite>  INSERT INTO tracks (geom, inserted_at, updated_at) VALUES (X'00A000000500000F1100000066', '2023-10-17', '2023-10-17');

Error: tracks.geom violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]
```

And when I do manage to get the insert

```
spatialite> INSERT INTO tracks (geom, updated_at, inserted_at) VALUES (st_geomfromtext('multilinestring((10.02 20.01, 10.32 23.98, 11.92 25.64), (9.55 23.75, 15.36 30.11))', 3857), DATETIME('now'), DATETIME('now'));

spatialite> INSERT INTO tracks (geom, inserted_at, updated_at) VALUES (GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRINGZ((18.68056 54.695338 15.6,18.68061 54.695331 15.6,18.68069 54.695339 15.6,18.680783 54.695356 15.8,18.680868 54.695368 15.8,18.680947 54.695379 15.8,18.681009 54.695388 15.8,18.675521 54.692955 22.4))', 3857), DATETIME('now'), DATETIME('now')
```

It does not come out quite right on the Elixir side

```
iex> t.geom |> Geo.WKT.decode
{:error,
 %FunctionClauseError{
   module: Geo.WKT.Decoder,
   function: :do_decode,
   arity: 2,
   kind: nil,
   args: nil,
   clauses: nil
 }}
```

Same for WKB decode

Is there something missing in the column create?

Comment: The inserts with st_geomfromtext look good to me even I think that inserting a linestring into a table that is defined as linestringZ might fail. And by looking at the coordinates I believe that they present EPSG:4326 data, not EPSG:3857. So I think that you have valid SpatiaLite geometries in a database. I have no idea about what happens on the Elixir side. But is t.geom a SpatiaLite geometry blob? That is not WKT nor WKB. Use the functions AsWKT or AsBinary https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It got me thinking about t.geom being a blob and you were right it was just basically an elixir binary so they were not speaking the same language

In the end had to resort to raw SQL and then it worked as expected with selects using spatialite

` def build_sql() do
    """
    INSERT INTO tracks(geom, name, updated_at, inserted_at) VALUES (SetSRID(GeomFromText(?), 3857), ?, DATETIME('now'), DATETIME('now'));
    """
  end`